# How to print a 2D array in a Function C Programming

Tags: c, arrays

I'm new to 2D arrays, structs and have a limited knowledge about pointers. My problem is that the display function only displays addresses. i dont know which part of my code is wrong or missing. can you give me suggestions to fix it or ideas? Thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>


struct Inventory
{
    char name[100];
    float latestCost;
    int stock;
    int sold;
};
struct Inventory *getInfo(void);
void display(struct Inventory *items[][4], int n);
main()
{
    char select;
    struct Inventory items[10][4];
    int i,n,j, *ptr;

    printf("\nEnter how many items in the inventory:\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);

     ptr = malloc(sizeof(struct Inventory));

    for(i= 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        items[i][4] = *getInfo();
    }
    display(&items,n);

    getch();
}
struct Inventory *getInfo(void)
{
    struct Inventory *items = malloc(sizeof(struct Inventory));
    assert(items != NULL);
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("\nName of the item: \n");
    gets(items->name);
    printf("\nCost:");
    scanf("%f", &items->latestCost);
    printf("\nStock:");
    scanf("%d", &items->stock);
    printf("\nTotal Sold:\n");
    scanf("%d", &items->sold);
    return items;
}
void display(struct Inventory *items[][4], int n)
{
    int i, j;

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            printf("%d\t", items[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

}
```

Comment: `ptr = malloc(sizeof(struct Inventory));`? `ptr` is an `int*`

Comment: Why do you pass the address of `items` to display? Just pass `item` instead of its address .

Comment: `printf("%d\t", items[i][j]);` doesn't make any sense at all. You need different format specifiers for each element in `Inventory`.

Comment: so like this? printf("%c%.2f%d%d", items.name, items.latestCost,items.stock,items.sold);?

Comment: No. Do what @AlterMann suggested in his answer

Answer (score 2):

Here

```
void display(struct Inventory *items[][4], int n);
```

you want a pointer to an array of 4 `Inventory`s, not a 2d array of pointers to `Inventory`, change to

```
void display(struct Inventory items[][4], int n)
```

or

```
void display(struct Inventory (*items)[4], int n)
```

---

Here

```
display(&items,n);
```

you don't need to pass the address

```
display(items,n);
```

is enough

---

```
printf("%d\t", items[i][j]);
```

`%d` prints an integer, use some member of the struct:

```
printf("%d\t", items[i][j].stock);
```

or

```
printf("%d\t", items[i][j].sold);
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for commenting. I tried your solution but im getting an output of some weird addresses. i'll double check again and ill try to fix it. :)

Comment: still getting some bunch of addresses  :(

Comment: Note that `fflush(stdin);` is undefined behavior and `gets()` is dangerous, show us the inputs

Comment: i added the fflush(stdin) because whenever I enter how many items in the inventory, after that, it immediately asking for the costs. it skips the name of the item.

Comment: The correct way to flush `stdin` is `int c; while ((c = fgetc(stdin)) != '\n' && c != EOF);`

Comment: Okay, for some reason, i dont know what i did but i followed what you told me and it displayed the way i want it. thank you for your help! :D